# Does the ZGC garbage collector support string deduplication?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, zgc

Since it is not listed as an option at https://wiki.openjdk.java.net/display/zgc/Main I assume it is not supported. Some [tests code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/zgc/zgc/file/5cc6acb1d6b6/test/hotspot/jtreg/runtime/appcds/sharedStrings/ExerciseGC.java) made me wonder if it is supported?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As of this moment, it looks like ZGC will support string deduplication as of Java 18 (from the [pre-release notes](https://jdk.java.net/18/release-notes)):

> Build 11
>
> ZGC supports string deduplication ([JDK-8267186](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8267186)) *hotspot/gc*
>
> The Z Garbage Collector now supports string deduplication ([JEP 192](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/192)).

Answer (score 0):

Per Liden, the ZGC project lead, stated on 2020-04-02:

> ZGC doesn't do String deduplication (yet).

[Source](https://mobile.twitter.com/perliden/status/1245721968810299392)

Comment: Is there an issue anywhere for this to be implemented? That is, when I come back and look at this answer in a year, how will I know if this is still valid or not?

Comment: Ah. I found the issue, and added an answer for that.